# Make a runnable link to Colaboratory notebook

Tags: url, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Someone share a Jupyter notebook via Google Drive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B88HiG_KpEbQcVhNa1NpZzVrT3c/view?usp=sharing

I want to make the link a runnable version on Google Colab instead.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First take the ID part from the Drive URL.
Here the ID is 0B88HiG_KpEbQcVhNa1NpZzVrT3c

Then put it in the fileId parameter in Colab URL, like this.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B88HiG_KpEbQcVhNa1NpZzVrT3c&offline=true&sandboxMode=true

Notice the offline and sandboxMode parameters. Without them, the notebook will be read-only. In that case, you need to either duplicate it or change to playground mode to make it runnable

### update

Newer URL is in this format instead:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/0B88HiG_KpEbQcVhNa1NpZzVrT3c#offline=true&sandboxMode=true

Answer (score 3):

Easiest method- when the notebook is open in Colab:

1. Click the Share button in the top right.
2. Copy the link provided at the top of the Sharing dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
from google.colab import auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import pandas as pd

auth.authenticate_user()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

file_id = '1h1z-vGcNk1pt2U9Q8g9NR_L14txKLEos'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(downloaded.getvalue()))
```